# Switch to a tag in TortoiseGit and go back to initial state

Tags: git, tortoisegit

My question is strictly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070178/tortoisegit-how-do-i-temporarily-switch-to-an-earlier-version): I have Tortoise Git and I need to *temporary* switch to a previous state where I placed a tag, then make a modification of **that** version and after rollback to the current state, losing the modification made (so I want to go back to the initial state).

Since I cannot mess up with the code, is the procedure explained in the related question sufficient? Should I select the option "Create a new branch" when I switch back or not? If I don't, later on can I just use:

- Explorer -> Switch/Checkout
- Select branch
- master OK

to come back to the initial state?

**EDIT**
For instance what happen if in [this window](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-checkout.html#tgit-dug-checkout-dia-1) I switch to a certain tag without selecting the option to create a new branch? Would I be able to switch to the master initial state again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> have Tortoise Git and I need to temporary switch to a previous state where I placed a tag

You can create a tag without switching.

1. go to log
2. select branch (upper left) - you can also choose a branch which isn't local.
3. choose commit and select "Create Tag at this version..." in contextmenu

Steps 2 and 3 in screenshot:

[image]

> then make a modification of that version

It's the best to create a new branch, so from same log and same commit, choose "Create Branch at this version..."

[image]

> (so I want to go back to the initial state).

Switch back to your original branch.

Comment: Ok, but I already have a Tag and I am in a situation in which I have multiple commits after the Tag. So I do not need to create a new one, I only need to switch back to this Tag I have previously created, make a modification (in your case creating a new branch but I do not really need it), export my project and switch back to the master initial state.

Comment: anyway, making changes in separate branches is never a bad idea.

Comment: In the end I created a new branch. I will probably never merge this branch to the master, but to stay on the safe side, it was probably the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of direct commands, what you want to do here is to checkout a previous commit in the detached HEAD state.  Then, you want to maybe poke around there, test some things, and finally return to your original state.  You may do this in Tortoise Git by doing `TortoiseGit → Switch/Checkout`.  Check the `Tag` radio button, and enter the name of the tag.  By clicking `OK`, you will checkout that tag.  Once you have finished doing your work, you may return to where you were by again checking out your current branch.

By the way, in terms of raw Git commands, you would do this:

```
# from master
git checkout <some_tag>
# poke around
git checkout master
```

See the [Tortoise Git documentation](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-checkout.html) for more information.

Comment: For posterity: I read the documentation but it doesn't say what happens if I work at "no branch" switching back to a tag and back again to Master. It only says: "If you checkout/switch to a Tag or Commit, you should create a new branch. Otherwise you will work at no branch." This is enough for making me creating a branch when I switch back otherwise I suppose it can be dangerous.

Comment: @Rexam It isn't dangerous per se, it just means you are working in the detached HEAD state.  If you made a bunch of commits there, and wanted to keep that work, then yes you would create a new bona fide branch.